# debugging a function about days between dates

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

```
# Credit goes to Websten from forums
#
# Use Dave's suggestions to finish your daysBetweenDates
# procedure. It will need to take into account leap years
# in addition to the correct number of days in each month.
def daysInMonth(year,month):
    if month in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12):
        return 31
    elif month in (4,6,9,11):
        return 30
    elif month == 2:
        if year%4 ==0:
            return 29
        else:
            return 28

def nextDay(year, month, day):
    """Simple version: assume every month has 30 days"""
    if day < daysInMonth(year,month):
        return year, month, day + 1
    else:
        if month == 12:
            return year + 1, 1, 1
        else:
            return year, month + 1, 1

def dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    """Returns True if year1-month1-day1 is before year2-month2-day2. Otherwise, returns False."""
    if year1 < year2:
        return True
    if year1 == year2:
        if month1 < month2:
            return True
        if month1 == month2:
            return day1 < day2
    return False        

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    """Returns the number of days between year1/month1/day1
       and year2/month2/day2. Assumes inputs are valid dates
       in Gregorian calendar."""
    # program defensively! Add an assertion if the input is not valid!
    assert not dateIsBefore(year2, month2, day2, year1, month1, day1)
    days = 0
    while dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
        year1, month1, day1 = nextDay(year1, month1, day1)
        days += 1
    return days

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8), 585 ),
                  ((1900,1,1,1999,12,31), 36523)]

    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()
```

the issue is that in the last case it doesn't show the correct answer and my mind is flipping over the matter and i can't find where is the problem, I changed the code many times but the problem still occurs.

can someone guide me through the issue step by step?
P.S: I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be a typo in the last test_case, the answer is just one day more: 36524. When you have that as the last argument it show that it passed. Please let me know if you are complete sure that the answer you were given is correct.

Comment: it is the correct answer if we don't include the late date

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What do you mean with "late date"?

Comment: sorry, *including last date*

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. The last date, one day after that it is correct. Your code isn't wrong, the last answer is wrong